# My boolean cutter appears with flipped normals

Tags: modifiers

I am using boxcutter, and when I use difference boolean it appears with flipped normals, and instead of cutting into mesh, it appears as union. Everything is same on those both booleans, however, on this left on it doesn't cut in, on the right one you can see it's cutted. What could be problem?

[image]

Comment: maybe ask the seller of this add-on?

Comment: Since the _Box Cutter_ tool for the most part only sets modifiers and other options that are already in Blender, it has to do something with the meshes themselves I guess. At first I would suspect the part you're using as cutter has flipped normals, at least this is what usually makes the cut-outs appear red. But then there's also Z-fighting between blue and red faces. Could it be that the main object and the cutter both have _Mirror_ modifiers? To cut both sides it's sufficient that the main object is mirrored if the _Mirror_ comes after the _Boolean_.

Comment: The box in front might be because your mesh is non-manifold. The one on the side is simply because your still showing the cutter object.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann applying mirror on object, and then cutting it with boolean fixed it. However, only on this specific mesh, on other it works just well with booleans + mirror. There is no double vertices, and normals are good, I checked already.
Now it works fine, even with mirror. Sort of just "restarting" it worked.

Comment: @Radoon Hard to tell without comparing your files, but be aware that the order of modifiers is sometimes (or rather most of the time) important.